# How to send http request as sending from another ip in React/Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs

**Using frameworks : React/NodeJs**

I'm trying to play video streams from a video source provider that having good security. I'm handling all data and communication from my server side and sending required data for client running on browser.

there is a special request that need to execute from client side. that will enable client's ip address allowed for streaming from streaming server.

If I send this special request from my server then, the streaming server allowing only for my server ip address. So client will get '403 (Forbidden)' error when streaming on his browser.

I need a way to do this somehow. So my questions are,

**1) Is there any way to send that request from client's browser (Failed because of CORS). I don't need the response. but need to send request to streaming server by client's real IP address?**.

**2) If I handle that request from my server side is there any way to set the requesting IP address to fake(client's) IP?(Don't need get the response)**

Thanks for any idea

Answer (score 0):

An IP address can not be forged in Node. Maybe there are specialists who can do it at the kernel level of the system, but it seems to me that I have mistaken IP with MAC.

You will have to do streaming through your servers.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. do you think there is no way to send the request from client browser? So streaming server will allow client's IP once received it from browser. not sure when it blocking by CORS server will get the request or not

Comment: It used to be something that was done by applet java / flash. But maybe they also began to respect CROSS. If you write a browser add-on, it should be able to download data from any page. But I will not give a guarantee. And this solution is not available on mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks. I know that about browser addon. But trying to make it easier for the users. Seems like I have to do the streams from my server